# C++ question defining an array outside of main()

Tags: c++, arrays, global, definition

I can't find a reason why the code below wont work when I define the array (with an identical line) in two different places. Whether this is good practice is NOT my questions. I just want to find the reason.

```
// Array Test: t.cpp
// If only the ONE LINE in question is enabled in either place
// it works/fails as indicated. I wonder why?

#include "iostream"

int a = 5; // Rows
int b = 4; // Columns

// int x[a][b]; // if done here: NoGo! WHY? <<<***************************

int main () {

int x[a][b]; // if done here: OK!           <<<***************************

for (int r = 0; r < a; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < b; c++) {
        x[r][c] = (r*10+10) + (c+1);
        std::cout << x[r][c] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
  }
std::cout << "\nARRAY CREATED \n\n";
}
```

Comment: The size of an array has to be a compile-time constant. Neither `a` nor `b` is a compile-time constant. That line marked "if done here: OK!' is not legal C++. 
Some compilers allow that as an extension.

Comment: If you add `constexpr` to both variable declarations, it should also work if you declare the arrays at file scope.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel -- `const` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

If you define your array globally, its size needs to be known at compile time. Within a function, the array will be created on the stack, so its size may be variable (but see remark below). Your variables `a`, `b` are not constant, so their value is not known at compile time.

By declaring them constant instead, it works as you expect:

```cpp
const int a = 5; // Rows
const int b = 4; // Columns

int x[a][b];
```

Remark: Variable-length arrays (i.e., non-constant size specifiers) are a C99 feature and not part of any current C++ standard.